# How to change email account details in appcfg.py google appengine SDK

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have hosted GAE apps with two different email ids! When i first time used appcfg.py to `update` my app then it prompted me for email id and password but later it doesnot. How to i change the saved email id and password? I tried to use `--email=` flag with appcfg.py, but it dint worked.

Comment: @Adam: even if i use `--email` flag appcfg.py still uses the same email+password pair which i had provided in first run without asking me the password for the new email which i have provided with `--email` flag.

Comment: thanks for the additional info. I have duplicated this behaviour and found an easy solution in the documentation. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use the `--no_cookies` flag, e.g.:

```
python2.5 /path/to/google_appengine/appcfg.py --no_cookies update myapp
```

From [the documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp.html):

> --no_cookies
>
> Do not store the administrator sign-in credentials as a cookie;
>   prompt for a password every time.

I've just tested: using this flag will bring up a prompt for your email address as well.

Comment: The `help` mentions a `--email` flag and `--passin`, but it doesn't seem to work. Thanks.

Comment: using --no_cookie, you will have to key in password every time you run appcfg.py update. To make appcfg.py remember your new credential, first rm $HOME/.appcfg_cookies, then appcfg.py update . --email=<email>, then key in password when prompted, afterward just use appcfg.py update . without having to key in password again.

Comment: I just had to empty the file at $HOME/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens, and when trying to update the code it prompted me for authentication to new account. Your comment was very helpful in locating this file.

Answer (score 4):

```
appcfg.py update . --no_cookies
```

This command does work but needs to be authenticated everytime. Instead clear the earlier configuration in .appcfg_oauth2_tokens, such that when you try to update using appcfg.py the next time, the new authentication credentials will be saved.

Comment: You're right, the $HOME/.appcfg_cookies is not used any more, it's $HOME/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens now. If you remove the .appcfg_oauth2_tokens file you will promoted for authenticating the next time you use appcfg.py update.

Answer (score 3):

**Add a new account:**

```
gcloud auth login
```

complete the login process

**Set this account as default:**

```
 gcloud config set account username@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 2):

```
rm ~/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens
```

This would allow you to login via browser when you try update again.

Answer (score 0):

Answer of Adam Bernier also can apply when you use the 
appcfg.py **download_app** for downloading app from appengine servers.